# Going up two or three folders using dirname twice or three times

Tags: php, dirname

Take a look at the code

```
$link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
echo dirname(dirname($link));
```

Question 1. Is it elegant to use dirname twice to go two levels up?

Question 2. In case you want to go three levels up, would it be a good practise to use dirname three times?

Comment: If it is a fixed amount of level ups this is fine I think. But if it is always variable how many levels you want to go up. I would split the path by `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` and take an `array_range()` and `implode()` the new array again. Or use `str_repeat()` with `../` if it's a file path used by PHP and not exposed to the user in any way.

Comment: Most simple and elegant way to get 2 folders up would be `dirname( __DIR__ )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to be more flexible in how many levels up you would like to go, then I would suggest writing a small function to help take care of this for you.

Here's an example piece of code which might do what you would like.  Instead of using `dirname` multiple times or calling a `for` loop, it uses [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), assuming that `/` is your directory separator.

```
$string = 'http://example.com/some_folder/another_folder/yet_another/folder/file
.txt';

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  print "$i levels up: " . get_dir_path($string, $i) . "\n";
}

function get_dir_path($path_to_file, $levels_up=0) {
  // Remove the http(s) protocol header
  $path_to_file = preg_replace('/https?:\/\//', '', $path_to_file);

  // Remove the file basename since we only care about path info.
  $directory_path = dirname($path_to_file);

  $directories = preg_split('/\//', $directory_path);
  $levels_to_include = sizeof($directories) - $levels_up;
  $directories_to_return = array_slice($directories, 0, $levels_to_include);
  return implode($directories_to_return, '/');
}
```

The result is:

```
0 levels up: example.com/some_folder/another_folder/yet_another/folder
1 levels up: example.com/some_folder/another_folder/yet_another
2 levels up: example.com/some_folder/another_folder
3 levels up: example.com/some_folder
4 levels up: example.com
```

Comment: this is a solution, but it doesn't answer the question :/

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1. Is it elegant to use dirname twice to go two levels up?

I don't think it's elegant but at the same time it's probably fine for 2 levels

> Question 2. In case you want to go three levels up, would it be a good
>   practise to use dirname three times?

The more levels you have the less readable it becomes. For a large number of levels I would use a foreach and if it's used often enough then I'd put it inside a function

```
function multiple_dirname($path, $number_of_levels) {

    foreach(range(1, $number_of_levels) as $i) {
        $path = dirname($path);
    }

    return $path;
}
```